# OnClickListener on not always visible button inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-button

When the red button is pressed, the orange button **appears**.
When the red button is pressed again, the orange button **disappears**.
(Basically a toggle)

[image]

This happens with `notifyDataSetChanged()` and different `ItemViewTypes`.

Two questions:

1. Do I need to register `OnClickListener` every time, and **de-register** it too?
   Or does it de-register automatically when it is removed from `RecyclerView` through `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I just have to add it every time?
2. Should I put associated methods with register etc. in the Activity/Fragment or in the `RecyclerViewAdapter`?

---

`onCreateViewHolder` code:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
        View view;

        if (viewType == ADD_FOOTER_ITEM) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_sa_add_footer_item, parent, false);
            holder = new AddFooterViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == INPUT_ITEM) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_sa_input_item, parent, false);
            holder = new InputViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_sa_item, parent, false);
            holder = new CustomViewHolder(view, this);
        }

        return holder;
}
```

`recycler_view_sa_add_footer_item.xml` is basically just a FrameLayout with an ImageButton and some visual stuff in it. The question is about that one `ImageButton`.

Comment: Do you have separate ItemViewType for orange button? Or it's just another view in the same item?

Comment: @Alex.Marinovskiy Yes, it's a different ItemViewType. It has to be at the end of the list, that's why I add it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. If you do not unregister you have not to register it back. OnClickListener will be always there attached to ViewHolder in ViewPool.
2. The best way is to define your Listener inside RecyclerViewAdapter and register it in `onCreateViewHolder` method.

Comment: The problem I had with that was that the method would have to reference variables from the `Activity`/`Fragment`, that the Adapter doesn't have. So it seemed like it might be better to make a method in the Activity instead of having to use Interfaces or something to give a callback to the Activity.

Comment: Well, I went with an interface that calls back to methods in the actual Activity. I guess that's the cleanest way to do it without passing objects through 3 methods back and forth. I guess your answer helped me with that so have the green checkmark :)